# nvidia drivers not installing and detect in my laptop on additional drivers tab

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, additional-drivers

my corei7 is not detecting nvidia graphic card.Not showing on additional drivers tab and also not installing from downloaded file .whats problem please help me

Comment: What is the output of the terminal command `sudo lspci -k | grep -iEA3 'VGA|3D'`?

Comment: now fix this problem with these commands

Answer (score 0):

Now fix the problem with nvidia drivers not installing with below commands

sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime

~# apt-get install nvidia-384 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime